# Dynamic model relations in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, model

I'm trying to define the relations for a specific Model depending on environment variables.
Like this:

```
class Book extends AppModel {
    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

        if (Configure::read('prefix') == 'admin') {
            $this->hasMany['Page'] = array(
                // ...
                'conditions' => array( /* all pages */ )
            );
        } else {
            $this->hasMany['Page'] = array(
                // ...
                'conditions' => array( /* only public pages */ )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

You could argue that I should apply these conditions in the query. But because I'm working with deeply nested relations I wanted to keep conditions centralised.

Now the problem that occurs is: if the `Page` model has relations to e.g. the `Paragraph` model and from the BookController I'm trying:

```
$this->Book->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Book.id'=>1),
    'contain' => array('Page' => array('Paragraph'))
));
```

... CakePHP will tell me that `Paragraph` is not related to the `Page` model.

If I create the relation by defining a model attribute all goes well:

```
class Book extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Page' => array(
            // ...
        )
    );
}
```

Why is this? Do I need to manually establish those relations? Is my timing (`__construct()`) incorrect and should this be done elsewhere?

Kind regards,
Bart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your timing is incorrect. You should either apply these configuration options *before* invoking the parent constructor:

```
if (Configure::read('prefix') == 'admin') {
    // ...
}

parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
```

or use `Model::bindModel()` instead which will create the necessary links:

```
$this->bindModel(
    array('hasMany' => array(
        'Page' => array(
            // ...
            'conditions' => array( /* ... */ )
        )
    )),
    false
);
```

See also [**http://book.cakephp.org/...html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly)