# Why we can't define relationships in the model constructor?

Tags: php, cakephp

My habtm relationship work just fine when I'm doing it as a public property. As soon as I try to move the code in the constructor, I get an error.  Question (I'm not a PHP expert) : what part of PHP I'm missing (or some magic in Cake) ?

I've read those : [Cake Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html), [PHP Constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

This will work :

```
class SupportIp extends SupportAppModel {
    public $name = 'SupportIp';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'SupportGroup' => array(
            'className' => 'Support.SupportGroup',
            'joinTable' => 'support_groups_support_ips'
        )
    );
```

This will not :

```
class SupportIp extends SupportAppModel {
    public $name = 'SupportIp';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'SupportGroup' => array(
                'className' => 'Support.SupportGroup',
                'joinTable' => 'support_groups_support_ips'
            )
        );
    }
```

Defining the relationship in the constructor, trigger this error :

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'on clause'
SQL Query: SELECT `SupportGroup`.`id`, `SupportGroup`.`name`, `SupportGroup`.`created`, `SupportGroup`.`modified` FROM `cominar`.`support_groups` AS `SupportGroup` JOIN `cominar`.`support_groups_support_ips` ON (Array)
```

Only defining it as a property, work perfectly.

**EDIT:**

It's a timing problem. 
An answer has been given here : [Dynamic model relations in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244011/dynamic-model-relations-in-cakephp)  Unfortunately, it doesn't say why.

By moving the constructor AFTER the relationship, it's working.

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'SupportGroup' => array(
            'className' => 'Support.SupportGroup',
            'joinTable' => 'support_groups_support_ips'
        )
    );

    parent::__construct();
}
```

More about it : [Associations on the fly](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic model relations in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244011/dynamic-model-relations-in-cakephp)